# Tree files update in obsidian?

Tags: obsidian

I'm working on developing a plugin for Obsidian and have encountered an issue. When I create a folder named 'oo-soso', it is successfully created and visible in the file tree. However, when I add another folder, 'ssss-soso' (as shown in the attached image), the 'oo-soso' folder disappears from the file tree. Interestingly, it can still be found using the system file explorer.

Can anyone advise on how to refresh or update the file tree after adding a new folder? Is there an API or specific function that can resolve this?

[image]

I expect that no folder will be hidden after it is created.

Comment: *"When I create a folder named 'oo-soso'..."* : Please include the code you are currently using, see [mcve] for more information